# The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hololens, filepicker

I am trying to use filepicker for my hololens app. But I can't use it because my project can't add the 'windows' reference.

When I write `using Windows.Storage`

`The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found` -- This error message appears with red line under Windows.

I tried to add reference with reference manager, but I can't find anything such as Windows at the Assemblies - Framework.

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: What project type?

Comment: Reiterating @SLaks - what type of project?  I was able to start a Unity 3D project, add a script and I have access to Windows.Storage; -- same for starting a new blank UWP app.  Let us know, and love to help. :)

Comment: @SLaks Thanks, Application - output type says class library. Is that why?

Comment: @LanceLarsen Thanks, Application - output type says class library. Is that why?

Comment: [Manohar Reddy Poreddys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53043140/9928822) works perfectly if you replace 8.1 with your Windows version.

Answer (score 3):

Win 8.1 SDK was missing for me, so got the error.

Below steps resolved my issue:

```
Download and Start the "Visual Studio installer"  
  Click on the "Modify" button  
    Click "Individual components" tab  
    Under "SDKs, libraries and frameworks" heading  
      Select "Windows 8.1 SDK" (replace 8.1 with your Windows version.)  
      Click "Modify" to install
```

Hope that helps.