# 'Windows' reference showing warnings and path is missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have visual c# project and this project has reference for 'Windows', however it shows warning and has missing path. May I ask what do I need to add in my visual studio 2017 installation to resolve this warning. You may see attached screenshot. Thank you.
 [image: Snip]

Comment: Read, research and include the actual compiler warning.

Comment: CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?... compiler error. And thanks @CodeCaster I'll keep on researching.

Comment: No, that's an error. Find the warning that indicates why the reference can't be loaded.

Comment: Yeah @CodeCaster. Here is the warning. "The referenced component 'Windows' could not be found." and I think I've missed something on my installation because 'Windows' is an assembly and may part of something when installing and I just couldn't figured out.

Comment: There must be more warnings. Read them all.

Comment: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Windows". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. That's all @CodeCaster.

Comment: I had this same error today. Posted a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53043140/984471