# How to fix "MediaElement doesn't contain definition for CurrentState"

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I was trying to implement a code found [*on*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.currentstate) , but that doesn't work .

My code is : `mediaStateTextBlock.Text = m.CurrentState.ToString();`

It says  ***MediaElement doesn't contain definition for CurrentState***

Can anyone please tell me what is the problem ?

Update :
Still problem is not solved .

[image: error - 1]
[image: error - 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add reference to `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll, Windows.dll` DLLs

Comment: Please see , I have edited the post . I have also downloaded 'Windows 8.1 SDK' as I read in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443661/the-type-or-namespace-name-windows-could-not-be-found) , but no luck .

Comment: I had some problem in my previous setup, I re-installed windows for some reason and this thing worked, although it has been more than 1 month since than. I just saw this question without tick yesterday and came to tell you **thanks**